# Checking to see if a string is alphabetic

Tags: java, performance, beginner, strings, array

```
public class Alphabet {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 checkAlphabetic("fdsfsfds+");

 }

 public static boolean checkAlphabetic(String input) {
 char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
 int count = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
 if (Character.isLetter(chars[i])) {
 count = 1;
} else {

count = 0;
break;
}
}

if (count >= 1) {
System.out.println("alphabetic word");
return true;
} else {
System.out.println("word is not alphabetic");
return false;
}

}
  }
```

I know people will say to use regex as it's more efficient but our tutor wanted us to use loops, as we haven't learned about regex yet (old school course).

Comment: In Java 8: `return input.chars().allMatch(Character::isLetter);`

Comment: The syntax of that is strange. For example havent seen :: before...looks like Ruby

Comment: The `::` operator is used to make a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). The syntax is new in Java 8. It's purpose is essentially to pass a method as a parameter. Your course instructor will likely not accept this as a solution, because it is often treated as an advanced topic.

Comment: In the point of program structure, you shouldn't print anything inside the check function, just return a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not harder than this:

```
public static boolean checkAlphabetic(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i != input.length(); ++i) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The idea is to return `false` as soon as you encounter a character `c` for which `Character.isLetter` returns `false`. If no such, return `true` since the string does not contain non-letter characters.

Comment: nice implementation, very simple. however the for loop, it would also work if you said : i <= input.length()...?

Comment: @Iona-KathrynEvans No, for the last iteration `i` will be `input.length()` which is one past the last accessible index.

Comment: what about i < input.length() or i == input.length()-1....?

Comment: @Iona-KathrynEvans `i < input.length()` would be more idiomatic.

Comment: @Iona-KathrynEvans `i == input.length() - 1`: unless length is 1, it will exit immediately without iterating a single time.

Comment: @coderodde What? how?

Comment: @Darkhogg The for loop will continue to loop for as long as the condition is true. Since the starting value for `i` is 0, `i == input.length() - 1` will only be true if `input.length() - 1 == 0`, or `input.length() == 1`. Otherwise, the condition will return false and the program won't even enter the loop at all.

Comment: @Abion47 Oh, I see, I completely misread the condition as `!=`, you are completely right.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can use an [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) if you are using Java 5 or superior.

```
public boolean checkAlphabetic(String input) {
    if (input == null) return false;
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Using an enhanced for loop will be slightly less performant in this case, because `toCharArray` must make a copy of the internal character array.

Comment: @4castle -- "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. " -- Donald Knuth

Comment: I'd only remove the null-check: I personally prefer to get `NullPointerException` so I know I passed a `null` value, and then I try to avoid calling the method at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my optimisation further:

```
public class Alphabet {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 checkAlphabetic("fdsfsfd432423423!");
 }

 public static boolean checkAlphabetic(String input) {
 char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
 int count = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
 if (Character.isLetter(chars[i])) {
 count = 1;
} else {

System.out.println("String is not alphabetic....");
System.exit(1);
return false;
}
}
System.out.println("alphabetic word");

return true;
  }
}
```